# Smoother scrolling on an infinite page

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is a long shot, but here's what's bothering me: I have a page which can go infinitely (so to speak) in all directions. It's an `overflow: hidden` on the main div and I can move by dragging the screen or with arrow keys. The data displayed inside is just ascii text (loads of it, rendered in loads of tables, long story, not allowed to change it). I've optimised it to cleanup after itself and regarding network traffic and sheer rendering into the DOM, everything is fine. There are no lags/hiccups no matter how much I drag the screen and move around.

However, it doesn't look/feel as smooth as a page with less content on it. My guess is it either looks different form a pure optical perspective, due to the amount of noise on the page OR the DOM is taking a beating by so much content and doesn't perform the way it should be (i.e. it doesn't lag, but it doesn't perform ideally, as well).

Anyone experienced with these kind of issues? Any scrolling/optimisation tips for lots of content in the visible part of the page? Or could it be just an optical thing? I know this question might be a bit wide, but it is what it is.

Comment: give us a link to see,,, if it' ok course..

Comment: @oserk loved to, but it's not out there on the web, nor am I allowed to put it anywhere :-( I know that makes the problem much more difficult for others to check out.

Comment: it could be a bunch of things,, dom, js, ajax or whatever,, this is too broad q,, sorry

Comment: Does the page load all the content in the div when the page loads? or does it load when you move the page?

Comment: @CodyPace there is an initial load that loads the visible part of the page + a buffer in all directions. That takes a couple of seconds and that's ok. When you move around, it calculates where you are, fetches the data for those coordinates and adds the data to the wrapper div. I've tested it thoroughly, fetching isn't the issue, it's purely frontend.